# WPF MVVM dynamic collection of user controls in a wrap panel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF but have created a window with a wrap panel that contains a collection of user control instances dynamically added from code behind.  Each user control will ultimately display data from a row returned from a database call.  I'd like to make this follow MVVM but am a little stuck on the architecture.  I think I need to have a view model for the user control and a view model for the window that would possess an observablecollection of the user control view models.  How do I get that bound to a wrap panel on the view side so that the wrap panel sees the collection of user control view models and knows to establish a user control for each instance in the collection?

I think once this is all bound properly I can make a background worker that at a regular interval queries the database and creates / updates the user control view model objects and if I am inheriting from INotifyPropertyChanged and firing property changed events in my user control view model everything should update based on the binding.  Does that sound correct?

I've seen basic examples such as an observablecollection of strings bound to a list box but I'm having trouble applying this to a more complex case.  Any suggestions as to a general architecture or where I should look to get started is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you need an enumerable control that has one item for each element in your ObservableCollection. The control's items will need to be templated to display the data using your custom control

To do this create an ObservableCollection which holds your data objects and use it as the ItemsSource for a ListBox. The ListBox will then need to be changed to display its items in a WrapPanel instead of the default layout. Modify the ItemTemplate of the ListBox to use your custom user control for each list item.

ViewModel:

```
public class WindowViewModel
{
     public ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseObject> DatabaseObjects { get; set; }
}


public class MyDatabaseObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     public string DbName 
     { 
         get { return _dbName; }
         set { 
                _dbName = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("dbName");
         } 
     }

     private _dbName;
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseObjects}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MyUserControl Title="{Binding DbName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you - the ObservableCollection and DataTemplate were the pieces of the puzzle I was missing

Comment: @jav1981 If you've received an satisfactory answer please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the `ItemsControl` class? With `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` set to a `DataTemplate` for your ItemUserControlViewModel (-> item user control view).  And `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` set to an`ItemsPanelTemplate` with a `WrapPanel`.

ItemControl's `ItemsSource` property would be bound to your `ObservableCollection<ItemUserControlViewModel>` from `WindowViewModel`.